# what is the best way to save achart to database and report chart by crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a chart in my form which I created by passing y values as an array which is inserted to database as text separated between numbers by (,) like this:
`127,116,106,100,96,90,81,78,78,74,69,66,63,60,59,57,55,51,48,44,38,34,32,28,24,19,17,15,12,10,8,6,6,6,4,4,4,2,2,3,2,2,3`

Now I want to report that chart which created on the form. I suggest two solution to start:

1.converting chart to image and store it in database as an array of bits and adding it to crystal report.

2.use the  string above to create a new one in crystal report but I don't know how I pass that value to y axis

I created the chart on the form and I can save it as image by using that code below

```vb
 Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()
 If dlg.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 
 Me.chart1.SaveImage(dlg.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Png)
```

Comment: your chart already has the values, you can use parameter fields in crystal reports which takes the chart values and you won't need a database for that.
Btw that's a lame way to save chart values.

Answer (score 0):

One of the 3rd-party UFLs listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl) can generate a Crystal chart from an array of numbers.

Here's an image showing some options:

[image]